# What trace length is considered short in case of buck voltage regulator

Tags: pcb, voltage-regulator, pcb-design

I'm working on LM2596 based voltage regulator circuit that will be printed on PCB.

According to LM2596 datasheet some traces should be kept as short as possible. However no numbers are given.

This is my design (with ground plane hidden), from left to right:

- LM2596S voltage regulator
- SS54 Diode
- 12.5mm 100uH Inductor
- 2x Low impedance 300uF capacitor

First attempt:

[image: Design]

I'm a little bit worried about C In (capacitor on the right between input voltage and ground) connection with regulator. The trace length is about 35mm.

Next attempt:

[image: Design]

Comment: Shortness on PCBs usually relates to frequencies and inductances. You are likely fine, its quite short.

Comment: I don't understand why your diode appears to be connected to the feedback node.

Comment: For a buck, you want the high current loop areas to be as small as possible. If you can find a way to make the GND of your output filter cap to be close to the GND of the input cap, that would be advantageous. Diode GND should also be close to output cap GND to keep the other high current loop area small.

Comment: Looking at the datasheet, the component connections don't make any sense. Does eagle have red for the bottom layer? Even if it does it still is weird.

Comment: @Daniel I Have also no idea why I did this. I ALMOST ordered this board, so by just one comment you saved a lot of money and stress. Thank you one more time.

Comment: Everybody's done it. Glad I could help prevent one.

Comment: I've updated the image.
@whatsisname, eagle has red for top, blue for bottom.

Comment: Are you limited to a single side load on this board, or can you do a double side load?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, I don't know what does 'load' mean, but I can use both sides for signals and only top for elements

Comment: One more thing -- I take it the pads that appear to be unconnected are actually connected to the ground plane?

Comment: Yes, the ground is 'hidden' beacuse otherwise it is quite illegible. This is how it looks with ground: http://imgur.com/2EkZekD

Comment: TI has an application note for [PCB layout around simple switcher](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva054c/snva054c.pdf).  Section 4 discusses what they imply by "as close as possible".

Comment: What I understood is that for buck regulators, the CIn and catch diode should be the closest to IC

Comment: I made a next attempt to make it as good as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping of the LM2596, catch diode, inductor, and Cout aren't too bad. But, Cin is too far from the LM2596 (as you were worried).

With a buck, there are two main signals that need to be minimized:

- The current loop from Cin through the LM2596 and catch diode needs to be as short as possible. This is a pulsed current, most likely the highest current, and richest in harmonics on the board.
- The switching node: pin 2 of LM2596 and it's connection to the inductor and catch diode, also needs to be minimal. This voltage signal is very rich in harmonics, and is the primary source of common mode noise.

The easiest way to minimize the input current loop is probably to take the LM2596, catch diode, and Cout as a group and rotate them 180 degrees. This will allow Cin to be much closer to the LM2596.

Minimizing the switching node could be done by rotating the inductor by 90 degrees, ending with the inductor input very close to the cathode of the catch diode.

Currents through the inductor and out to the load aren't such a concern. It's mostly DC with some ripple current (contained by Cout), and not that harmonically rich.

Additionally, it will be desirable to have some input filter inductance to reduce EMI for the rest of your system. Probably a common mode choke, which if you choose well will have enough leakage inductance to also use differentially. (You may already have this, but couldn't see any in the board section shown)

Comment: This is what i did: http://imgur.com/yCon0QE

Answer (score 2):

As to loop area, while your design is probably fine as is -- there is one improvement you can make to it.  Simply rotate the output capacitor 180 degrees and delete any stitching vias that are in the way of the new routing for the Vout trace.  This shrinks both the D-Cout and the Cin-Cout loops, and makes it so they don't have to traverse stitching vias, either.

HOWEVER, you do have a problem with this layout that should be corrected before you go and get a board made -- the via connecting Cin to the Vin trace on the bottom needs to be not in that pad, lest it turns into a manufacturing headache, sucking all the solder away from that pad and leaving Cin disconnected on one end. Oops!